# DB2 unique constraint, unique indexes and performance

Tags: sql, indexing, db2, unique, unique-constraint

I have a table that requires two rows to be unique. They are likely to be joined regularly so I probably need an index on these rows.

I checked the Infocenter on the [Unique constraint](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0020151.html) and on the [Unique Index](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000919.html).

I'm wondering about the difference and the performance impact. Both seem to create an index. The unique index allows one null value. Are there other important differences?

Do these indexes improve query performance or are they just enforcing uniqueness? Should I add an additional index for performance reasons or will be the unique index be good enough? Unfortunately I don't have enough test data yet for trying it out yet.

Comment: First line of your unique constraint link: "Unique constraints ensure that the values *in a set of columns* are..." - so where did you get "allows for one column only" from?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hmm. Having a deeper second look at the [ALTER TABLE Statement](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0000888.html) you could be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique constraint or Unique Index has no performance differences and any one would suffice. During query processing DB2 optimizer would automatically pick up indexes created for maintaining unique constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You will find explanation in this topic : http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/185707-difference-between-unique-constraint-unique-index

Explaination in one quote :

> A unique index is a physical thing whereas a unique constraint is a data
>   modeling construct. As was already stated, unique constraint are
>   implemented by adding a unique index (and additionally requiring the NOT
>   NULL condition).

Comment: Actually I already found this link through google. It didn't answer the performance aspect though and I'm not sure if that information from 05 is still up-to-date. Unique constraints for foreign keys still seems to apply nowadays.